# Calendario en Android

Tags: java, android, calendar

Buenas, necesito incluir en mi aplicación un sistema de control de asistencias, para eso necesito mostrar una especia de calendario donde se muestren las asistencias, como podria hacerlo para mostrar esto en una actividad? Necesito alguna pista o idea para saber donde empezar!. Gracias!

Comment: ¿Ya has investigado en Internet?, recuerda que no es Yahoo respuesta y que a menos que muestres un mínimo esfuerzo mostrando tu código y/o errores alguien te ayudaría, aquí un ejemplo de calendario https://www.movilzona.es/tutoriales/android/desarrollo/curso-de-desarrollo-android-tema-12-practicando-con-los-views-en-android-studio-un-reloj-y-un-calendario/ y http://tublogdelprogramador.blogspot.mx/2014/05/popup-para-seleccionar-una-fecha.html

Comment: Ya había visto esos 2 links, preguntaba en cuanto al sistema de asistencias que es mi verdadera duda, gracias y saludos!

Comment: Este tipo de preguntas se deben hacer mejor en el chat. Las preguntas deben estar formuladas para un problema concreto, y que se pueda dar una respuesta concreta que lo solucione. Lo que preguntas es demasiado amplio y probablemente sea cerrada. Mas info: [¿Como elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - [¿Qué tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Busca una librería de calendario en [Android Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/27?sort=created), es muy buena y hay de todo tipo de componentes, no solo calendarios